# Complexity of a particular pseudocode algorithm

Tags: complexity-theory, big-o, time-complexity, pseudocode

I'm just studying for my data structures & algorithms final.  The following question was on my midterm and I got it wrong, so I'm just trying to figure it out:

> **What is the complexity of the following pseudocode?**
>
> ```
>  x <- 0
>  for x <- 0 to n:
>    for y <- 0 to n:
>      y <- y + 1
>      y <- y * 2
> ```

On the midterm I answered O( n^2 ) but now that I'm looking at it again, I think it might be O( nlogn ).. See my answer below showing my attempt.

What is the correct answer?

Any help is helping me pass my exam!

Cheers!

Comment: I'm not sure why I got downvoted for this.  I am not getting people to do my homework for me.  I am trying to clarify my understanding of Big-Oh notation for my final.  I attempted to answer this problem on my midterm and failed.  Now I'm clarifying.

Comment: See the answer http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/170610/what-is-the-big-o-time-complexity-of-this-algorithm. Your question is very similar to that.

Comment: Still not sure why I am being downvoted for this question.  It would be great if you could provide an explanation as to why I am being downvoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is my answer for the moment...

The outer loop `for x <- 0 to n` executes n times, definitely.

The inner loop `for y <- 0 to n` appears to execute n times, however every time it executes, its contained code brings y exponentially closer to n.  So I believe that this section of code executes with O( logn ) complexity.

Thus, the whole algorithm executes with O( nlogn ) time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Empirically, I may dare to represent your algorithm's behavior as such:

[image]

Some snapshots ("sum" is the number of iterations):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
500 * 8 = 4000
```

[image]

[Logarithm calculator link](http://www.1728.org/logrithm.htm)